# How to update a single cell using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my code. I am doing a many to many relation between two objects a product and transaction. But when I inserted the updated stock and the transcations in their respected tables. The row in the product which I try to update the stock of becomes all null. This is the update logic

```
session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
SQLQuery sql = session.createSQLQuery("update Inventory set inventoryqty="+e+
    "where inventoryid='"+
    Integer.parseInt(mf.getMf().getSellingForm().getItemBox().getSelectedItem().toString())+
    "'");
sql.executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Please put your image with code in your question as text

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: Did you guys understand what I am trying to say?

Comment: not able to get what you want and what your problem is

Comment: what didn't you get?